# Reporting Services : adding permissions for a user that is not recognized yet

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using Reporting Services for SQL Server 2016. If we want to enter a new user and gives him permissions on reports we know that we can use report service interface in order to enter a new user which will be tested if it really exists else the message user or group name is not recognized is displayed.

Is there away to enter permissions for a user that doesn't exist yet? I mean a user which it's Sid is null

Answer (score 1):

Use Active Directory.  Set up a group, such as "SSRS Browsers", within AD.  Ensure any and all users who require access to the reports (including new users) are listed in this group.  Then give the AD group the right level of access within SSRS itself.